# how to set row height dynamically when have to show dynamic data in cell template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Is there any way to set the height of row dynamically, I mean I am rendering data in a cell using cell template where have used ng-repeat and the data I am repeating is dynamic can increase or decrease in count. So i need a way to adjust the row height.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your problem.You can use `ngGridAutoRowHeightPlugin`
http://plnkr.co/edit/0J5XbE?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for answering but it didn't work for me, self.init() function is always getting by passed don't know why. And this plugin is for ng-grid and I am using ui-grid where css classes are different, I changed css class according to ui-grid but the problem is self.init() is not executing.

Comment: can you please insert your source code.maybe i can try out.i had the same problem in ng-grid i solved it.